# Performance: expand binary image (morphological dilation)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, cython

I wrote a Cython function which expands a binary image (numpy array) by 1 pixel. So I want simply to expand the area where array values are 1.
Here is my naive approach:

```
def expand_1px (numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint8_t, ndim = 2] A):
    cdef int  h = A.shape[0]
    cdef int  w = A.shape[1]
    cdef numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint8_t, ndim = 2] RES = numpy.zeros([h, w], dtype = numpy.uint8)
    # These Two lines below were originally missing 
    cdef int  y, x
    cdef unsigned char  prev, cur

    for x in range (0, w):
        for y in range (1, h):
            prev = A[y-1,x]
            cur = A[y,x]
            if cur > prev:
                RES[y-1, x] = 1
            if cur < prev:
                RES[y,x] = 1
    for y in range (0, h):
        for x in range (1, w):
            prev = A[y,x-1]
            cur = A[y,x]
            if cur > prev:
                RES[y, x-1] = 1
            if cur < prev:
                RES[y,x] = 1
    return numpy.bitwise_or(A,RES)
```

This works correctly, but <s>is miserably</s> slow. 
An OpenCV function dilate() is <s>1000</s> ~30 times faster than my Cython variant and gives same result. I use it like this:

```
kernel = numpy.ones((3,3), dtype="uint8")
kernel[0,0] = 0
kernel[2,2] = 0
kernel[0,2] = 0
kernel[2,0] = 0
...
IMG = cv2.dilate(IMG,kernel,iterations = 1)
```

---

**Q**:

- How can be OpenCV's variant so fast? What it does actually?
- How can I make my Cython function work so fast?

---

**Update**:

Such bad performance was due to missing 'cdef' declarations, my bad. Adding this to the function makes the difference:

```
cdef int  y, x
cdef unsigned char  prev, cur
```

Still the performance difference is about 30 times which is also kind of dissapointing. Any advice for further improvement?

Comment: *"How can I make my Cython function work so fast?"* You could start with declaring more (perhaps all) of your local variables (.e.g `x`, `y`, `prev`, `cur`) with the appropriate C type; see http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you. Youre right of course, I knew I probably do a noob mistake. Still it is ~ 30 times slower than OpenCV variant, I'll update the question.

Comment: Have you used the `-a` command line option so that the cython command generates a colorized HTML version of the source?  The dark yellow lines are lines that result in Python calls instead of generating pure C.  For best performance, you want to tweak the cython code so that there is no yellow in the loops.  (Those loops look pretty simple, so if all the variables have C declarations, it is likely that you don't have any python calls left in the loops.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Those lines with `numpy.` calls are marked yellow. And it is not surprising. Others are white now.

Comment: Are you using compiler directives? See http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiler-directives . In your case at least you should set *boundscheck* and *wraparound* as False. Besides, you can change use *elif* instead of the second *if*.

Comment: @sebacastroh thanks, _boundcheck(false)_ helped indeed a lot! _wraparound(false)_ and _elif_ almost did not change the speed, probably 1%. So now my function works only ~8 times slower than CV's, a great improvement though.

Comment: @sebacastroh sorry, desinformation, it is other way around - _wraparound(false)_ is what makes it faster, not _boundcheck(false)_.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big issue with your function: you are doing more loops that you need.

```
import cython

@wraparound(false)
def expand_1px(numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint8_t, ndim = 2] A):
    cdef int  h = A.shape[0]
    cdef int  w = A.shape[1]
    cdef numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint8_t, ndim = 2] RES = numpy.zeros([h, w], dtype = numpy.uint8)
    cdef int  y, x
    cdef unsigned char  prev, cur

    for x in range(1, w):
        for y in range(1, h):
            cur = A[y,x]

            prev = A[y-1,x]
            if prev < cur:
                RES[y-1,x] = 1
            elif cur < prev:
                RES[y,x] = 1

            prev = A[y, x-1]
            if prev < cur:
                RES[y,x-1] = 1
            elif cur < prev:
                RES[y,x] = 1

    for x in range(1, w):
        cur = A[0,x]
        prev = A[0,x-1]
        if prev < cur:
            RES[0,x-1] = 1
        elif cur < prev:
            RES[0,x] = 1

    for y in range(1, h):
        cur = A[y,0]
        prev = A[y-1,0]
        if prev < cur:
            RES[y-1,0] = 1
        elif cur < prev:
            RES[y,0] = 1

    return numpy.bitwise_or(A,RES)
```

Originally, you were doing `2wh` iterations, with this change you will only do `wh + w + h` iterations.

Comment: This is nice. But this has _exactly_ same performance as mine, tried also with bigger arrays. Less iterations but same amount of operations I suppose, so you just collect both passes in one loop.